# Alternative for ternary operator in the case a ? a : b without repetition

Tags: javascript, jsx, expression, conditional-operator

The scenario is the following: I want to return the value of a when a is defined and else I want to return b. I need an expression because of JSX.

I am looking for a better way to write the expression `a ? a : b` where a and b are variables. I was trying `!a&&b`. The problem is when a is defined, then it returns of course `false` instead of the value of a which I want to receive then. I think I have my wires crossed at the moment. If someone has an idea, I would highly appreciated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a default approach with a [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()). This returns `a`, if this values is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), otherwise the default value of `b`.

```
a || b
```